# Getting a DynamicResource in code

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

the FrameworkElement's FindResource method allows to get resources defined in this frameworkelement. however, i have some dynamic resources located in another assembly loaded at runtime.
Accessing it with DynamicResource from within XAML is no problem, but i wonder how i can get access to Dynamicresources from code (e.g. datatemplateselectors).
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DynamicResource` essentially defers the resolution of the resource until runtime, and creates a link between the consumer and the resource so that changes to the resource still propagate to the consumer. It still uses `FindResource`.

If your external resources are merged into your visual tree you should still be able to find them with `FindResource`. If not, you can use [pack URIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) to load them manually.